# iOS - What is the "CI" reserved word NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, nspredicate, predicate

I noticed that the "ci" word is a reserved word for predicates in iOS according to [Apple official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html). (see at the bottom of the page) :

[image]

But there is no link and I can't find any documentation about it.

It seems that a lot of people use [c] but rarely/never [ci].

Does anybody have an hint ?

Comment: Well `[ci]` would be the same as `[c]` since putting an i in the brackets doesn't mean anything.  I don't know why "CI" is said to be reserved but neither "CI" nor "CASEINSENSITIVE" are in the set of reserved words that `NSPredicate` actually checks at runtime fwiw.